# Server Error response when i change the api url parameters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, http

I have a code that call an external API using laravel controller. The code works fine before until one day i tried to make a call it gave me an error response. This API is supposed to be returning a historical data of indonesian stock price.

For some reason it works if i pass "BRIS" to this method but gave me this error when i pass any other stock ticker like "GOTO" or "BBCA".

`"message" => "Server Error"`

I tried calling the API through the documentation, it works just fine. Here is my method on the controller.

```
public function oneWeek($ticker)
    {

        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        $monthBefore = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' -1 week'));
        $response = Http::acceptJson()
            ->withHeaders([
                'X-API-KEY' => 'API_KEY_REMOVED'
            ])->get('https://api.goapi.id/v1/stock/idx/' . $ticker . '/historical', [
                'to' => $today,
                'from' => $monthBefore
            ])->json();

        //$data = $response['data']['results'];
        //$data_historical = array_reverse($data);
        dd($response);
        return $data_historical;
    }
```

Here is the result if i use "BRIS" as my parameter in the method for $ticker

[Success with the $ticker "BRIS"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZmRv.png)

But here is the result if i use any other stock ticker such as "GOTO" or "BBCA" as my parameter in the method for $ticker

[Error Message if any other than "BRIS" is used for $ticker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVFe6.png)

it works with every stock the first time i wrote the code and i never mess with it since. It just randomly stops working and only worked with the stock ticker "BRIS"

any help would be appreciated.

(EDIT)

I already tried postman and it did the same thing i will try to contact the API developer(s). Thanks you for the feedbacks!

Comment: Try doing it with Postman first. Also with those other tickers. The Api gives a response, so there might not be a lot you can do about it

Comment: You shouldn't share your API Key like this.

Comment: Looks like that's the response from the API you're trying to access, so you probably want to contact them.

Comment: then contact your API service provider, problem seems to be at their end !!

Comment: aah im sorry i forgot to remove the api key. this is my first question on stackoveflow. Thank you for removing it!